# Encapsulation - accessor methods

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have always tried to follow principles of encapsulation when coding.  For example, doing this:

public class Student

```
private Name As String

public sub setName(ByVal name2 As String)
  Name = Name2
End Public
```

Instead of allowing clients to access properties directly, like:

```
Dim s1 As Student
s1.Name = "Mark"
```

All the books say it is bad practice to follow option two as it means client code could break if you change the class.  However, I don't fully understand why this is the case.  If you remove the Name member then client code will break regardless of whether you allow them to access the property directly or not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, `Name` is not binary compatible with a property or method signature returning `String`. So if you create a public member, and then change it to a property later, it will break any client code that originally called the member.

More info here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Other reasons:

- You get more fine-grained access control with properties.
- You can add breakpoints to properties.
- You can add logging to properties.
- You can add validation to properties.
- Properties are used for data binding; fields aren't.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the bullet points.  Can you explain what you mean by: "Name is not binary compatible with a property or method signature returning string"

Comment: `Public Name As String` and `Public Property Name As String` are not equivalent API's.  You can't change from one to the other without recompiling the client.

Comment: One more thing.  Can you clarify what you mean by: You get more fine-grained access control with properties.

Comment: You can make properties publicly gettable, but privately settable. Combined with a constructor, this makes your object more deterministic, because you set your state when you construct the object, and nobody outside the object is allowed to change that state unless you let them. You can also allow properties to only be changed by classes that inherit the containing class (Protected).  More info at http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/blinheritancea.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Property you can define it in an interface, which is not possible with a field. Also you can differentiate between getter and setter, and thus create readonly "fields". The idea is to give as few options to the outside as possible, so you have less scenarios to think about.

Comment: I like the notion of read only fields (+1).  Can you elaborate on what you mean by: "If you have a Property you can define it in an interface".

Comment: Since properties are basically methods you can use them in interfaces in the same way too.

Answer (score 1):

Using these kind of empty properties, that do nothing but assign given values to fields, or return field values is code bloat. This is not encapsulation.

Encapsulation, in its true essence, is when fields are totally hidden from outside, to the point that any code outside not even know how many fields there are, yet alone types or values of the fields. Then any processing that need to be done on the fields are done by public methods of class.

An example is a mail class. It not matter to outside world in what format you are storing email addresses, either you are breaking the domain part in a separate string for example. The inner working of a class, which is what values are put in private fields in what way must be totally opaque to outside.

Its like somebody asking you for a loan. That person need not know where you put the money, in wallet, in safe, in a bank account whatever. That person also not need to know how much total money you have. You, the class, is responsible for taking out the money and giving it.

I do this by making all fields private. A lot of my methods are also private. Its just a handful of public methods that are used in message passing. Also the values are never returned by reference, always by value, so outside world cannot change data in my class without going through the filter of my methods.

A property is actually a method. Whenever you have a method, you must do some unique processing. Processing is logic, have conditions or loops or both. Conditions might be hidden in form of polymorphic behavior but are still conditions. If you don't have any processing to do then there is no need of the method.

Comment: I am not sure this is the best example as surely a bank would need to know how much money you have before they can approve a loan? Could you clarify? I would normally use properties in .net rather than setters (like Java).  I used a setter to quickily explain the question.

Comment: The point is, if money is not already in a bank account, then bank has no business knowing where I am putting my money. It can be in my wallet, in my safe, even under my mattress. Bank should ask me how much money I have, not go and check it directly by breaking in my house. In the example in the answer, I am not asking bank to give me loan, I am giving loan to a friend to help him.

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  +1 for the analogy.